# If/Then Statement writing, for blank cell to pull from another

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I am trying to write a IF/THEN statement for a blank cell to pull from the one next to it.  Basically if N2 is blank then pull from O2 but otherwise pull from N2.

This is what I have so far: =IF(ISBLANK(inuput!N2), input!O2, input!N2 )

Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Your formula works fine for me. Or maybe what do `N2` and `O2` contain? Or you're just misspelling `ISBLANK(inuput!N2)`

Comment: I tested and this works fine for me. As @zummontt has said you have misspelled the name of the sheet `inuput` vs `input`. Or any other cell/parenthesis, but the syntax of the formula is completely fine.  Could you check that and reach back to let us know?